# Install Debian safely without destroying Windows

Tags: debian, partition, windows, dual-boot, debian-installer

I have Windows 7 running perfectly. I want to have both Debian and Windows, So what I want is dual-boot.
I just almost installed Debian Jessie 8.2, but I had to abort because I don't know what to do in the partition step. The step offers a couple of options, [here's](https://www.google.com/search?q=debian+jessie+installation+partition&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=633&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7tdT4usPJAhUGfZAKHYWhCNsQ_AUIBygC#imgrc=iPkCmFNXIfb5wM%3A) a picture. By the way, above all of these my installer provided a fifth option called: "Guided - use the largest continuos free space".

For more information to resolve this issue, I include the following picture of partitions, when you click on manual (one of the options of the last link , the step in wich I am stuck)

[image: This is what Installer shows after pressing manual mode and scrolling two lines to the bottom to be able to see the important particular information of my disc, the first two lines not showing were a couple of general commands of installation, found on all installations]

This is what Installer shows after pressing manual mode and scrolling two lines to the bottom to be able to see the important particular information of my disc, the first two lines not showing were two of general commands of installation, to configure RAID and other configure something (i don't remember right now).

Now I provide the last piece to understand my question. That being that my system, viewing it with Windows 7 , is already partitioned it seems. There is a C:/ partition that Windows folder and all files are installed and next to it there is D:/, wich is empty. How do I install Debian on that partition, can I do that?

Here I show you C: and D:, when I click on my computer:

[image: My computer]

So, please help me. I provide you with information if needed.

1) Can I install Debian in D:?
2) Where is D: in the list of drives that appear in Manual?

Comment: you'll be installing on SCSI1 on partition 5.. that's the D:\ drive (#5 logical)

Comment: How do you know that's the D:\ drive? In Windows Dis 343 GB. But the #5 partition is 369.4 GB. There is a big difference, what's the explanation?

Comment: The difference is that some software shows disk sizes in powers-of-two (where 1kB is 1024, 1MB is 1048576 bytes etc - technically, these are now called kibibytes and mebibytes), and some show disk sizes in powers-of-10 (1KB = 1000, 1MB=1000000).  The difference is small but adds up to a lot when you are talking about gigabytes/gibibytes of data.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Units_of_information

Comment: as for how to tell: since /dev/sda5 is the only partition even approximately close to the size of your empty D: partition, it's the only one that it can be.

Comment: as per @cas, installer show power of 1000, windows power of 1024. 344/(1.072) is 344.58. 1.072 is ratio of gigbytes to Gigabyte (round to first order).

Comment: @cas Thanks you were right with the different units argument! See my own response to see how it ended.

Answer (score 2):

Consider your computer's hard disk as a city.
You can build many buildings in this city. in computer language we call this buildings Partitions.
There are 4+1 Potential Powers in this city. They must have the best house in town. We call the first 4 one "Primary Partitions" and the other one as an "Extended Partition".
Windows and any Unix system are the Potential powers so they must go into Primary Partitions.

## Example 1

---

`in Unix we name the hard disk as sda, sdb, sdc and ...`

We have a computer with one hard disk which has 4 Primary Partitions.

`--sda\
   \sda1 100GB Windows NTFS
   \sda2 100GB Debian EXT4
   \sda3 100GB Ubuntu EXT4
   \sda4 100GB Parsix EXT4`

Well in fact there will be a problem with this scheme.
the problem is (WTF!) which one is the first power of our city?
Power of the mayors of our city (Operating systems) is something called BOOT.
Windows is so selfish. if we give him the power of the boot it will only boots it self up.
But Unix Operating systems use a boot system called GRUB.
GRUB is not selfish it will even goes and find other powers together so you can choose which one should be choose in the election.
there is a question remains... WHICH OF THESE 3 OTHER UNIX SYSTEMS MUST HAVE THE BOOT POWER.
The answer is the one which is nearer to the beginning.
So The hard disk will find it faster.

## Example 2

---

If we gather people of the town together we can create another power called Extended Partition.
With this power you can take any of the Unix OS out of their mansions (Primary Partition) and put them inside a house where we can gather any other thing and give power to People (Extended Partition).

Heres the scheme:
`--sda\
    \sda1 300GB Extended
       \sda5 Debian 100GB EXT4 --> Logical
       \sda6 Ubuntu 100GB EXT4 --> Logical
       \sda7 Parsix 96GB EXT4 --> Logical
       \sda8 SWAP 4GB linux-swap --> Logical
    \sda2 100GB Windows NTFS --> Primary`

With the power of extended we can create a house named SWAP. and also gather any Unix System inside our city.

## Your Problem

---

To Tell the truth keeping windows in the first partition is not a good idea. cause we must boot from other partition and to make the computer boot fast we must create a boot sector at the beginning of the partition.
but it doesn't matter.
First you have to remove the partition number five that is a logical one and I don't know what is the 4th primary partition as long as we just have windows. I think it's a partition for installing debian.
to remove that partition you can use DISKPART in cmdline in windows.
something like:
`DISKPART> select disk 0
DISKPART> select partition 5 \\ You can list partition to see whats inside
\\ Remove the one you think is the logical one (FIND IT BY SIZE ITS 300GB)
DISKPART> delete partition \\ will delete selected partition.`

then you can use the live Debian or Ubuntu and use gparted, parted, fdisk to create an scheme like this:

`--sda \ 640GB ATA
   sda1 Primary 104MB ntfs >> This is a Microsoft Reserved partition for dirty stuffs Billy does.
   sda2 Primary 247GB ntfs >> This is Windows Partition.
   sda3 Primary (SPACE) ext4 >> This is Where debian goes put a boot label on it.
   sda4 Extended 4GB >> this is for swap
   sda5 logical swap 4gb >> place this logical drive inside the extended.`

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me: 
1) I didn't believe the drive D: in Windows was effectively SCSI1 partition #5 on the Debian installer because of the different sizes. By taking into account that the Debian installer was counting storage space with decimal conventions (1 KB equals exactly 1.000 and not 1024 bytes) I was able to make a very simple calculation: 344 GiB (GiB is the binary "cousin" of GB) equals 344*1024^3 bytes)= 368293445632 bytes ≈368.3 GB wich is extremely close to the presented value in the installer. So this was enought evidence for me. I proceded to partition that disk chossing the "manual" way in root directory "/", home directory and swap area (this is explained in the tutorials everywhere around internet).
Conclusion: Windows still works. I didn't modify the partition in wich Windows it's installed, wich is C: or number #2 in any moment.